# Inherited a property from interface to class

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

```
interface IRestrictionUserControl
{
    public GeneralRestriction Foo{ get; protected set; }
}

public partial class RestrictionUserControl : UserControl, IRestrictionUserControl
{
    public RestrictionUserControl(Restriction r)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Foo = r;
    }
 }
```

I get the error: `The name 'Foo' does not exist in the current context`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: `Restriction` inherites from `GeneralRestriction`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must **Implement** Foo in the derived class.

```
public partial class RestrictionUserControl : UserControl, IRestrictionUserControl
{
    public RestrictionUserControl(GeneralRestriction r)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Foo = r;
    }

    public GeneralRestriction Foo
    {
        get; protected set;
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> An interface contains **only** the signatures of methods, delegates or events. The implementation of the methods is done in the class that implements the interface

**One more point:** Interface members cannot be defined with access modifiers. So you have to change your interface declaration like this otherwise it will not even compile.

```
interface IRestrictionUserControl
{
    public GeneralRestriction Foo{ get; /*protected set;*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the implementation for Foo in the class since an interface is only defining the contract for the property. Also, you have to remove the public keyword from the interface definition since all methods/properties defined by an interface are always public.

Comment: But this property does not have any implementation, just is a setter and getter of a value. (it is not a calculable implementation)

Comment: Yes, but it has to be defined in the class none the less. The interface is just a contract that creates a "promise" of certain behavior in an implementing class

Comment: @Overflow012 Your interface does not know that it's just a simple get/set of a backing value. The implementing class could very easily return a constant value (without a backing field) in the getter, and ignore the setter altogether (or throw exceptions, or who knows!) If you want to dictate that level of implementation detail, you would have to do it with an `abstract` class (but only do so if it makes sense)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair he can't do it in an abstract class since he already inherits from `UserControl` even if it would probably make sens

Comment: @ppetrov I don't see the technical reason that he couldn't create an `abstract RestrictionUserControl : UserControl`? I _don't_ think it's a good idea in this case, but I don't see why it can't be done.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I understood you were saying that he could "transform" his interface into an abstract class and keep everything else the same, that would have been impossible. But after reading your last comment I see I misunderstood you, and of course there is no technical reason that he couldn't create the `abstract RestrictionUserControl : UserControl`

Answer (score 1):

RestriccionUserControl = RestrictionUserControl?

I believe you have a typo

Answer (score 1):

You only inherit members and methods from classes not interfaces. Interface is a template of things which it's going to force the implementing class to have.

So if your interface has a public member property, you will need to implement it in the class, just like you do with the methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `GeneralRestriction Foo{ get; protected set; }` in an interface definition, it doesn't mean the same as in a class definition.

In a class the compiler will generate the getter and the setter (since C# 2.0 if I remember well), but in the interface you just say that your property must have a public getter and a protected setter.

So you have to implement them in the derived class as it was said in other answers, and by implement I mean just declare a getter and a setter (you can even copy paste the code from your interface into your class)